# Spinner for server side processing of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, spinner, server-side

I have a jquery datatable version 1.10 with server side processing. Everything is working fine. However my requirement is to show a spinner for every ajax call instead of default "Processing..." message. Tried multiple ways but nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
$("#table-pp").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "order": [[2, "asc"]],  
    "pagination": true,
    "language": {
        "infoFiltered": "",
        "processing": "Loading. Please wait..."
    },
    "serverSide": true,
    "destroy": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "/Site/test/GetData",
        "data": { param: XYZ},
        "error": function (e) {
        },
        "dataSrc": function (json) {               
            json.draw = json.draw;
            json.recordsTotal = json.recordsTotal;
            json.recordsFiltered = json.recordsFiltered;
            return json.data;
        }
    },
    "initComplete": function () {
        //spinStop();         
    },
```

I have two functions, i.e startspin and stopspin that i want to call once ajax call is made and after completion.

```
function spinStart() {
    $('#test_center').show().spin({ color: '#fff' });
    $('#test').show();
}


function spinStop() {
    $('#test, #test_center').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about your start and stop spin functions, the solution to your problem is to place these functions in the right place.

When you start ajax call, you call `spinStart`. 
Once the ajax call is finished, you call `spinStop` inside the ajax callback to stop the spinner.

Also, please provide your ajax call function with your question as well, it will be helpful to debug your issue.

**EDIT1:**

`"language": { processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '}`

That's FontAwesome spinner. Alternatively, you can replace it with a small spinner gif.

**EDIT2:**

If you somehow don't want to use GIF or FontAwesome, no problem at all.

It seems like ajax call success callback is not the direct trigger for DataTable to refresh and show the new data, so it won't work if you place `spinStop` function inside ajax success callback.

Instead, DataTable provides two functions to trigger a draw event, which are [preDrawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/preDrawCallback) and [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)

The workflow should be:

1. call `spinStart` inside `preDrawCallback` to show spinner
2. call `spinStop` inside `drawCallback` to stop spinner

```js
$("#table-pp").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "order": [[2, "asc"]],  
    "pagination": true,
    "language": {
        "infoFiltered": "",
        "processing": "Loading. Please wait..."
    },
    "serverSide": true,
    "destroy": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "/Site/test/GetData",
        "data": { param: XYZ},
        "error": function (e) {
        },
        "dataSrc": function (json) {               
            json.draw = json.draw;
            json.recordsTotal = json.recordsTotal;
            json.recordsFiltered = json.recordsFiltered;
            return json.data;
        }
    },
    'preDrawCallback': function(settings) {
      spinStart();
    },
    'drawCallback': function(settings) {
      spinStop();
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the code above, I already tried this in ajax object:                      
       beforeSend: function () {
            spinStart();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            spinStop();}                                     But it doesn't work, it works only for very fist call, successive calls to next pages doesn't fire this.

Comment: I did a bit more research on how datatable server side works.
Check out this link: http://live.datatables.net/kihecona/1/edit 

  I will update the answer.

Comment: That is pretty standard answer across all the forums but why i don't want that because i have the same funtion used throughout the app to show and hide spinner and i want uniformity in this case as well. I don't know if i need to create a css only for this requirement.

Comment: It might because that the ajax success is different from the table refresh event. It could be the datatable trigger table refresh in `drawCallback` function, but not based on ajax success callback. https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

So can you try putting `spinStop` inside `drawCallback`?

Comment: that works great, i mean drawcallback gets called each time when i am changing the paging but how about spinStart? Does datatable has something similar (just before when request gets fired)?

Comment: guess what? they do have a `preDrawCallback`, https://datatables.net/reference/option/preDrawCallback, give it a try

Comment: BUT, honestly, if I can do something in just one line of code, I won't be using two functions to do that, but people have preferences :)

Comment: it works!!! thanks so much, that made my day, i am marking your reply as answer (please update that). thanks a ton again.

Comment: No worries at all. I've updated the answer :) Cheers mate.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old but may help someone else. As it's just an ajax call you can use the 'beforeSend' and 'complete' functions to show and hide a loader.

Here is an example *(btw I'm using this library for the loading - https://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/)* -
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: true,
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    header: "jqueryui",
    pageButton: "bootstrap",
    responsive: true,
    colReorder: true,
    scrollY: 200,
    deferRender: true,
    proccessing: true,
    serverSide: true,

    ajax: {
        url: "PropertyLimitOverride",
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': $('@Html.AntiForgeryToken()').val() },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#listCard").LoadingOverlay("show", {
                background: "rgba(1, 56, 63, 0.5)"
            });
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#listCard").LoadingOverlay("hide");
        },
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {
            "name": "Added",
            "data": "added",
            "targets": 0,
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return new Date(Date.parse(data)).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
            },
        },
        {
            "name": "Address",
            "data": "address",
            "targets": 1,
        },
        {
            "name": "Limit",
            "data": "limit",
            "targets": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "EndDate",
            "data": "endDate",
            "targets": 3,
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return new Date(Date.parse(data)).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
            }
        },
        {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="/customers/edit/' + row.uprn + '">Edit</a> | <button>Delete</button>';
            },
            "sortable": false
        },
    ],
    order: [[0, "desc"]],
    drawCallback: function () {
        $('.page-item').removeClass('paginate_button');
    }

});
```