# Datatable how can i remove loading background

Tags: datatable, datatables

I'm trying datatable and using default loading wording "Loading ..." and having grey background. Then i'm trying to change loading type by using spinning indicator. But grey background still appear instead of spinning indicator only. How can i remove the default grey background?

My spinning indicator is below

[image: My spinning indicator]

My jquery code is below

```
$('#countries-table').DataTable({
    "processing":true,
    "language": {
        processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '
        // "processing": "Loading. Please wait..."
    },
    "serverSide":true,
    "ajax":"<?= base_url('app/getdata'); ?>",
    "dom":"lBfrtip",
    stateSave:true,
    info:true,
    "iDisplayLength":5,
    "pageLength":5,
    "aLengthMenu":[[5,10,25,50],[5,10,25,50]],
    "fnCreatedRow": function(row, data, index){
        $('td',row).eq(0).html(index+1);
    }
});
```

i'm already commented default text indicator

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spinner for server side processing of jquery datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860073/spinner-for-server-side-processing-of-jquery-datatable)

Comment: There are also other [related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+show+spinner+site:stackoverflow.com) you can research for more possible ideas, approaches and solutions. There are also non-SO resources such as: [jQuery DataTables: How to show loading indicator during table reload](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-show-loading-indicator-during-table-reload/), and [How to display a progress indicator for server-side processing](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41654/how-to-display-a-progress-indicator-for-serverside-processing).